Facebook real ads integration in flutter app
I want to integrate real facebook ads in my flutter app. The package I am using is 'facebook_audience_network'. I have setup and registerd my app in Meta Audience network, also got my 'AppId' and 'PlacementId'.
All the solutions that I got are of implementing test ads not real ads, in which they add testingId here,
FacebookAudienceNetwork.init(
      testingId: "a77955ee-3304-4635-be65-81029b0f5201",
      iOSAdvertiserTrackingEnabled: true,
);

but we dont need to add testingId in real implementation. My questions:

Then how do I init the real ads?
One solution that I got to implement real ads is this, is this the way to integrate real ads? i.e., first login then implement?

import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:facebook_audience_network/facebook_audience_network.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize();
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
  final adView = BannerAd(
    placementId: 'YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID_HERE',
    adType: BannerAdType.banner,
    listener: (result, value) {
      if (result == BannerAdResult.error) {
        print('Banner ad error: $value');
      }
    },
  );
  adView.load();
}


If I successfully integrate, will I be able to see the ads in debug mode? Or I'll have to release the app to see its working?

I tried the test ads, but I need to implement real ads.
